# Concurrent readers in .NET 4.0 C#

Tags: c#, .net, concurrency

I came across this puzzle in a programming contest where I am not supposed to use any inbuilt concurrent .NET 4.0 data structures.

I have to override the `ToString()` method and this method should support concurrent readers.

This is the solution which I came up with but I strongly believe it is does not support ***concurrent readers***. How can I support concurrent readers without locking the list?

```
class Puzzle
{
    private List<string> listOfStrings = new List<string>();

    public void Add(string item)
    {
        lock (listOfStrings)
        {
            if (item != null)
            {
                listOfStrings.Add(item);
            }
        }
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        lock (listOfStrings)
        {
            return string.Join(",", listOfStrings);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: By "concurrent readers" you mean multiple threads invoking `.ToString` simultaneously?

Comment: @KirkWoll Yes. I wan to support multiple threads invoking Tostring()

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because `List<T>` is just a `T[]` under the hood, there's nothing unsafe about *reading* the list from multiple threads. Your issue is that *reading while writing* and *writing concurrently* are unsafe. Because of this, you should use [ReaderWriterLockSlim](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim.aspx).

```
class Puzzle
{
    private List<string> listOfStrings = new List<string>();
    private ReaderWriterLockSlim listLock = new ReaderWriterLockSlim();

    public void Add(string item)
    {
        listLock.EnterWriteLock();

        try
        {
            listOfStrings.Add(item);
        }
        finally
        {
            listlock.ExitWriteLock();
        }
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        listLock.EnterReadLock();

        try
        {
            return string.Join(",", listOfStrings);
        }
        finally
        {
            listLock.ExitReadLock();
        }
    }
}
```

`ReaderWriterLockSlim` will allow multiple threads to enter the lock in read mode, but they will all block if/while something is in the lock in write mode. Likewise, entering the lock in write mode will block until all threads have exited the lock in read mode. The practical outworking is that multiple reads can happen at the same time as long as nothing is writing, and one write operation can happen at a time as long as nothing is reading.

Comment: You have a typo: it's the `ReaderWriterLockSlim` (not `ReadWriterLockSlim`).

Answer (score 0):

Since it doesn't look like Remove isn't a requirement, why can't you just return a string?

```
class Puzzle
{
    private string Value { get; set; }

    public Puzzle()
    {
        Value = String.Empty;
    }
    public void Add(String item)
    {
        Value += "," + item;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Value;
    }
}
```

Comment: This would not be safe; two threads simultaneously calling `Add` would set `Value` equal to its previous value plus *one* of the threads values, not both. You'd also end up with ",Value1,Value2,etc." as your output (a leading comma), but that's an issue with the implementation, not the approach.

Comment: That said, while it's not particularly *efficient* (lots of string copying, etc.), if the OP does not have to consider the case of concurrent writers, then fixing the leading comma issue might still solve the problem.

Comment: @Adam: and you could avoid the string concatenation inefficiencies by using `StringBuilder`. You'd still need to prevent multiple simultaneous writes, though.

Comment: @JimMischel: The beauty of Daryl's answer is its simplicity; if you complicate it with another construct, then it's going to come down to the problem definition (which isn't provided) to determine whether a `StringBuilder` or a `List` is better. FWIW, I don't know anything about the thread safety of `StringBuilder` (e.g., is it safe to call `ToString()` concurrently?), whereas I *know* that reading a `List` is safe.

Comment: @AdamRobinson Yes, the problem set said nothing about supporting concurrent writers, just concurrent readers.  And I had the same thought about the StringBuilder, and not knowing if it is thread safe.  So, don't use this in enterprise, but it would solve the "puzzle" as described.